# When did Quark save Kira from the Dominion?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion, ferengi

In a very small side-element of DS9 episode [The Magnificent Ferengi episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Magnificent_Ferengi_(episode)), Major Kira [says](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/534.htm):

> **Kira:** *Consider it payback, Quark, for rescuing me from the Dominion.*

Memory Alpha links the sentence to [DS9:Sacrifice of Angels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sacrifice_of_Angels_(episode)), however, I don't recall Quark saving Kira from the Dominion, neither in Sacrifice of Angels nor in any other episode.

**Can someone refresh my memory?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [Sacrifice of Angels](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/530.htm) Kira and Leeta, Rom and Jake were being held by the Dominion.

Quark (and Tora Ziyal) came in bearing [Hasperat Soufflé](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hasperat_souffl%C3%A9), hypo-sprayed the Cardassian jailer and killed the two Jem'Hadar guards before taking down the forcefield.

[image]

This seems to be the incident that she's referring to.

> (Quark enters brandishing disrupters. The Jem'Hadar spread out.)
>
> **QUARK:** *All right, no one move!*
>
> **ROM:** *Brother! I knew you would come.*
>
> **QUARK:** *It's a surprise to me. Now, just keep calm and stay where you are. Understand? Don't move. You, open the holding cells. I said,
>   open the holding cells.*
>
> **ZIYAL:** *You just told them not to move.*
>
> **QUARK:** *Right. Nobody moves except you. Now open the cells.*
>
> (The Jem'Hadar look at each other then tense up. Quark kills them both
>   in total surprise.)
>
> **KIRA:** *Quark.*
>
> **QUARK:** *Yes?*
>
> **KIRA:** *Take down the forcefields.*
>
> **QUARK:** *Forcefields?*
>
> (Ziyal takes a disrupter from Quark and blasts the control panel.)
>
> **KIRA:** *I'd kiss you, Quark, but there isn't time. We have to find a way to shut down the power to the main computer.*